# How to style jQuery datePicker Calendar?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to use datePicker in a div. I would like expand the height of the div as the datePicker calendar opens..

I have a div like that:

```
.dateBox{
    width:160px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

The problem is as you click on datePicker input and open calendar, .datebox height doesn't change.. I have been playing around but I couldn't figure it out...

How can I fix that?

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/fcrsznb1/2/

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Since the calendar itself is wrapped in an div container (class ui-datepicker-div) which has the position absolute, your container will not change, try to modify the container itself instead.

Comment: You cant, datepicker ui is created outside of your `.dateBox` unless you want to use _js_ to get the height of the datepicker.

Answer (score 13):

```
.ui-datepicker {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    font: 12pt Arial, sans-serif;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);*/
}

    .ui-datepicker table {
        width: 100%;
    }

.ui-datepicker-header {
    background: #3399ff;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family:'Times New Roman';
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #111;
}

.ui-datepicker-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;

}

.ui-datepicker-prev {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position: center -30px;
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position: center 0px;
}

.ui-datepicker thead {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;

    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;*/
}

.ui-datepicker th {
    background-color:#808080;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #666666;
    /*text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #fff;*/
    /*filter: dropshadow(color=#fff, offx=1, offy=0);*/
}

.ui-datepicker tbody td {
    padding: 0;
    /*border-right: 1px solid #808080;*/
}

    .ui-datepicker tbody td:last-child {
        border-right: 0px;
    }

.ui-datepicker tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}

    .ui-datepicker tbody tr:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0px;
    }

.ui-datepicker a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {
    display: inline-block;
    /*font-weight: bold;*/
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;*/
    /*filter: dropshadow(color=#fff, offx=1, offy=1);*/
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default {
      background: linear-gradient(#999999, #737373);
      color:#ffffff;
      height:40px;
      width:40px;

}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-hover {
    background: #33adff;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active {
    background: #33adff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    color: #e0e0e0;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #4d7a85;
    border: 1px solid #55838f;
    position: relative;
    margin: -1px;
}

.ui-datepicker-unselectable .ui-state-default {
    background: #D6E4BE;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to animate the datebox you can try using:

```
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ showAnim: "fold" })
```

You can use any of the effects listed here: http://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects/

Here's a jsfiddle showing you it working: http://jsfiddle.net/fcrsznb1/3/

If you are looking to do other things you might want to check out the docs.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ See if any options will do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thnx for the answer but I am just trying to add auto height to the div according to calendar height..

Answer (score 1):

Right click on `datepicker` box. Select 'inspect' (Ctrl+Shift+I) in Chrome or 'inspect element' (Q) in Firefox. Find the CSS style that you want to change.

Example:

```
.ui-datepicker {
font-size: 5%;
}

.ui-widget-header {
background: #77CC6D;
}

.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default:hover{
background: #77CC6D;
border-radius: 2px;
}
```

To change the date format, change the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'D, d-M-yy' });
});
```

D > Day
d > date
M > short Month (Jan)
MM > long Month (January)
m > month number (1)
mm > month double number (01)
y > year (17)
yy > year (2017)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference the datepicker classes themselves and change their styles.

Instead of using this

```
 .dateBox{
     width:160px;
     height:auto;
    border:1px solid blue;
 }
```

Change the name to this and see if that is what you were looking for

```
 .ui-widget-content{
     width:160px;
     height:auto;
     border:1px solid blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom CSS for the date picker:

Copy this into your CSS file. check this result [black and green datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAFTI.png)

```
/* datepicker css */

.ui-datepicker {
background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
background: #000000 -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #fff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: #000000 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color- 
stop(0%,#000000)), color-stop(100%,#34495e); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: #000000 -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#000000 0%, #34495e 100%); /* 
Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: #000000 -o-linear-gradient(top,#000000 0%, #34495e 100%); /* Opera11.10+ 
*/
background: #000000 -ms-linear-gradient(top,#000000 0%, #34495e 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: #000000 linear-gradient(top,#000000 0%, #34495e 100%); /* W3C */
font-size:11px;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #5BFEC8;
width: 300px;
}

.ui-datepicker table td {
text-align:center;
}

.ui-datepicker a {
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:none;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev {
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
float:right;
}

.ui-datepicker-title {
text-align: center;
font-weight:bold;
}

.ui-widget.ui-widget-content{
    border: 2px solid #5BFEC8;
}

.ui-datepicker th {
    padding: .7em .3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    color: #5BFEC8;
}

.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{
    border: 1px solid #5bfec8;
    background: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #5bfec8;
}

a.ui-state-default:hover{
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: #5bfec8;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: #5bfec8;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
    border: 1px solid #dad55e;
    background: #fffa90;
    color: black;
}

.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #5bfec8;
    background: #080808;
    color: #5bfec8;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
the information bellow is for Air Datepicker plugin (http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index.html)

If you want several datepickers with different styles, you can use `classes` option.
Set your class name as a value on particular datepicker initialisation:

```
$("#myInput").datepicker({
...
      classes: "my-datepcker-class",
...
});
```

This will render a datepicker with the main block like this:

```
<div class="datepickers-container" id="datepickers-container">
  <div class="datepicker my-datepcker-class ..." >
....
```

So you can override any inner style of this datepicker instance

```
.my-datepcker-class .datepicker--content {
/* CSS styles here */
}
```