# How to set bigger space between day items?

Tags: css, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Adding datetimepicker 4.17.47 into my  jquery 3.4/bootstrap 4.6  project I found
very narrow space between day items : https://prnt.sc/1r3r909

Opening bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css file I found and added next class:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.day {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 4px !important; // I added this property
}
```

After that space between day items became good, but area with time selection is
over space between day items : https://prnt.sc/1r3roq6

And without possibility to open this design
in browser's console dropdown picker I tried and failed to set more width to days block...

How that can be done ?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the Inspector on all the elements in the picker. There're a lot of elements so you'll need to adjust quite a few things to get it how you want. Not a lot of help, I know, but dynamically generated widgets like this are a nuisance to restyle. Do you really have to? 

Comment: That just the point as having datepicker dialog opened when I try to open Code Inspector(by right clicking) datepicker dialog  is closed and I can not to look into int code. Are there is some way to look into it?

Comment: There are some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474378/how-to-style-jquery-datepicker-calendar) on how to style it.

Comment: Is it the same component ?

Comment: Don't know - check it out. At least, it may give you some hints.

Comment: No, for sure these are different components with different css classes.

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found decision with manually modified classes :

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.day {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 4px !important;
  width: 20px
}


.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 2px dotted red !important;
  min-width: 39em !important;
}
```

and it helped!